# boolean matching using & operator

Tags: julia

Ok lets take this logic here:

```
dummy = [1 2 3 4 5]
num_test = convert(Array{Int64},3 .== dummy)
```

I get the result:

```
0  0  1  0  0
```

If I try and match two statements:

```
num_test = convert(Array{Int64},3 .== dummy & 4 .== dummy)
```

It doesnt evaluate:

```
0  0  0  0  0
```

As i am writing this, is this because in the `.==` vectored call its looking for `3 & 4` on the same index element position?

I can do similar operations in R. But same type of logic not transferring to Julia or am I using incorrect syntax Julia?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the operation you are trying to perform is to evaluate `3 .== dummy` and `4 .== dummy`, and then compare the two element-wise. Given this, there are two problems here:

1) Order of operations. You need `(3 .== dummy) & (4 .== dummy)`.

2) If you are on a recent v0.6, you should also be seeing a deprecation warning, since from v0.7+, you will need to broadcast the `&` operator. So use `(3 .== dummy) .& (4 .== dummy)`.

As I understand the question, the conversion to `Vector{Int}` part is fine, and should work as expected, although you could just write `Int.((3 .== dummy) .& (4 .== dummy))`.

Given all of the above, you should now see the following outcomes:

```
julia> Int.((3 .== dummy) .& (4 .== dummy))
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0  0  0

julia> Int.((3 .== dummy) .| (4 .== dummy))
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  1  1  0
```

One final note, I'm assuming you deliberately defined `dummy` to be a single-row `Matrix` rather than a `Vector`. If you wanted your final output to be a `Vector`, then you would use `dummy = [1,2,3,4,5]`